# Value get lost in python generator/coroutine

Tags: python, iteration, generator, coroutine

I was looking at http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/, which I am finding very interesting, but in an example there is a behavior I do not understand.

In the [bogus.py](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/bogus.py) example, reported here

```
# bogus.py
#
# Bogus example of a generator that produces and receives values
def countdown(n):
    print "Counting down from", n
    while n >= 0:
        newvalue = (yield n)
        # If a new value got sent in, reset n with it
        if newvalue is not None:
            n = newvalue
        else:
            n -= 1

# The holy grail countdown
c = countdown(5)
for x in c:
    print x
    if x == 5:
        c.send(3)
```

The sequence of numbers generated is 5, 2, 1, 0, and I can not understand where the number 3 is gone: after the `send(3)`, the variable `n` is correctly set, but at the second execution of `yield`, it looks like the value 3 is just non yielded to the for loop.

Can someone clarify me why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `3` was returned from `.send()`, but discarded. The generator produces `5`, `3`, `2`, `1`, `0`; but because the `3` is returned to the `.send()` call you don't see that value printed. The `for` loop never gets to see it.

What happens is this:

- first time the `for` loop calls `next()` on the generator, the code advances until `5` is yielded.
- `x == 5` is `True`, so `c.send(3)` is called. The code advances through the generator function, and `newvalue` is set to `3`.
- The generator does *not* pause there, it now has control. The generator runs through the `while` loop and comes back to the `(yield n)` expression. `3` is yielded. It becomes the return value for `c.send(3)`. The return value is discarded here.
- The `for` loop continues, calls `next()` again. The generator is continued again with `yield` returning `None`, loops round to `n -= 1` and yielding `2`.
- The `for` loop continues to call `next()` on the generator, `1` and `0` are yielded, the generator ends.

Qouting from the [`generator.send()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send):

> Resumes the execution and “sends” a value into the generator function. The `value` argument becomes the result of the current `yield` expression. **The `send()` method returns the next value yielded by the generator**, or raises `StopIteration` if the generator exits without yielding another value.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Great, thanks! I missed the fact, in your third point, that `send` is actually similar to a `next` and, hence, has a return value coming from the `yield`.

Comment: Adding from specification ([pep-0342](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/))  
2. Add a new send() method for generator-iterators, which resumes the generator and "sends" a value that becomes the result of the current yield-expression.  The send() method returns the next value yielded by the generator, or raises StopIteration if the generator exits without yielding another value.

Comment: I am a bit confused too by step3.
when n == 5, yield 5 and print it. Then, c.send(3) to trigger the yield 3 as a return value back to c.send() and assign the value 3 to newvalue

If my statement is True, then why when n == 3 to continue the next loop to hit the newvalue = (yield n) without yielding the value n but saying that value n == 3 was discarded?

Comment: @rickhau: what exactly confuses you?

Comment: I am confused by why the value is discarded when the next loop of (yield n) right after c.send(3)

I also tried to print out the newvalue right after the yield statement:

`Counting down from 5`
`5`
` -> newvalue =  3`
` -> newvalue =  None`
I am also confused why there are two iterations there? Is it caused by the  send() function?

Comment: @rickhau: The `c.send(3)` call has `3` as the return value, but nothing is done with that return value. Thus it is discarded. Compare that with `print 'send return value:', c.send(3)`; there the return value would be printed.

Comment: @rickhau: and `newvalue` is only ever set to anything other than `None` by using `c.send()`, which happens just the once. The rest of the time `next(c)` is used (by the `for` loop iterating), which means nothing is being sent and the `yield n` expression returns `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Thanks for your more information. By the rule, the return value of c.send(3) is triggered by yield but no statement to print. Then, it was discarded when c.send(3) executes. I can understand this portion..

However, I can not understand why 3 is not yielded in the next loop when executing newvalue = (yield n) with n == 3? It really confuses me that why 3 is not yield again here even though 3 was discarded when c.send(3) returned?

Comment: Because newvalue = (yield n) statement is re-executed again, I think it should yield 3 value. However, it seems that some mechanism will check if the value was yielded or not to decide if it has value for now to yield... This part looks odd for me and hard to understand.

Comment: @rickhau: why would the generator produce `3` **twice**? `c.send(3)` un-paused the generator, so the code in the generator continues, while the `c.send()` call waits for the next value to be yielded. `newvalue` is set to 3. Then `if newvalue is not None` is executed, `n` in the loop is set to 3. The generator `while` continues, and `newvalue = (yield n)` is called again, yielding 3. The generator now pauses, and `c.send(3)` has a return value, namely `3`.

Comment: @rickhau: The `c.send()` return value is discarded, nothing is done with it. The `for` loop continues, calling `c.__next__()` (Python 3) / `c.next()` (Python 2), and advances the generator again. The generator un-pauses, but now `yield n` returns `None`, because nothing is being sent by the `.__next__()`/`.next()` call. `n` is still 3, so `n -= 1` is executed and now `n` is set to two. The `while` loop continues, we get back up to `newvalue = (yield n)` and `2` is yielded to the `for` loop.

Comment: @rickhau: so the `for` loop received `2` as the next value from `c` and assigns that to `x`. `print x` then writes the character `2` to your terminal.

Comment: @rickhau: it seems people don't realise that `c.send()` *also* returns values from the generator. The generator still produces `5`, `3`, `2`, `1`, `0`, but the `3` is returned to the `c.send()` call, not the `c.next()`/`c.__next__()` calls (so to the `for` loop).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great. I think I mis-interpret the point when n is discarded. It is highly appreciated by this statement "The generator while continues, and newvalue = (yield n) is called again, yielding 3. The generator now pauses, and c.send(3) has a return value, namely 3". Now I understand that the 3 is yielded as a return value for c.send(3).. I was thinking that 3 was yielded when c.send(3) executes with n == 5. I was wrong. Thanks for your correction. I am clear now!!! Thanks again