# why the coroutine do not print the initial value None?

Tags: python, coroutine

This is a [follow-up co-routine question to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990624/value-get-lost-in-python-generator-coroutine/17990860?noredirect=1#comment42839394_17990860). This code snippet is also excerpted from david beazley's sample code (inline1.py)

Why the `Got: None` was not printed?

```
class Task:

    def __init__(self, gen):
        self._gen = gen 

    def step(self, value=None):
        # Run to the next yield
        try:
            fut = self._gen.send(value)
            # Future returned
            fut.add_done_callback(self._wakeup)
        except StopIteration as exc:
            pass

    def _wakeup(self, fut):
        # Handler of results
        result = fut.result()
        #print(result)
        self.step(result) # Feedback loop(run to next yield)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
    import time

    pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8)

    def func(x, y): 
        time.sleep(1)
        return x + y 

    def do_func(x, y): 
        result = yield pool.submit(func, x, y)
        print('Got:', result)

    t = Task(do_func(2,3))
    t.step()
```

Comment: This is almost the opposite of a SSCCE.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comments. Would you mind sharing your advice on where to improve? Thanks.

Comment: http://sscce.org/ would be the place to start -- or http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, the local equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I post my answer here.

### Understanding of s.send(None) vs. s.next()

First of all, we need to understand `s.send(None)` and `s.next()`.

Here comes an example to show that `s.send(None)` does the same thing as

`s.next()` to advance the generator to yield statement.

Excerpted from david's slide:

```
def line_splitter(delimiter=None):
    print("Ready to Split")
    result = None
    while True:
        print("not yielded")
        line = (yield result)
        print("yielded.. [line = %s]" % line)
        result = line.split(delimiter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = line_splitter(",")
    s.send(None)  # or use s.next()
    s.send("A,B,C")

Result:
>>> s = line_splitter(",")
>>> s.send(None)
Ready to Split
not yielded
>>> s.send('A,B,C')
yielded.. [line = A,B,C]
not yielded
['A', 'B', 'C']  # <-- Pause at line = (yield result)
                 # yield the result and wait for the next input from send()  


>>> s.send('E,F') # Now it receives the next input, so run to next (yield)
Yielded.. [line = E,F]
Not Yielded
['E', 'F']
>>>
```

Now, we can visit the inline1.py to walk through the code flow.

1) When `t.step()` is called, it will run `fut = self._gen.send(None)` to send `None` to advance

the generator to yield statement in `do_func()`

`fut = do_func(2,3).send(None)`

```
def do_func(x, y): 
    result = yield pool.submit(func, x, y)
    print('Got:', result)
```

The key to understand the code flow here is the functionality of generator.send(None).

The send(None) is to advance the generator starts. That means, the code will pause at

`result = yield pool.submit(func, 2,3)` but return the `pool.submit(func,2,3)` back to `send()`

In the meantime, the `pool.submit(func, 2, 3)` is being executed.

Then, it pauses at here to wait for the next value being sent to fill the result

==> `result = (yield)`  (Simplified)  Or `result = yield` <del>pool.submit(func, 2,3)</del>

However, we use the `fut.add_done_callback(self._wakeup)` to deal with the return `fut`

which is `pool.submit(func,2,3)` and its result is equal to `5`

So, when the `add_done_callback` is called, the `_wakeup()` will retrieve the result

from `fut.result()` which is `5`. Then push the `5` into `step()` again

2) Then, it comes to the next `fut  = self._gen.send(5)`

Now, the value `5` is being sent to the result. So, `result = 5`.

Then, it prints out the `Got: 5` here.

No more data is being yielded back to `send()` for `fut`, so the StopIteration is being raised

Then, the program ends.